# How to convert project in "AspectJ Project" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aspectj, monkeytalk

I've installed the AspectJ plugin in Eclips. I can create AspectJ project. Generaly it seems that I installed this plugin correclty.
But I cant convert my project in AspectJ, because there is no "AspectJ Project" when I make right mouse click --> choose Configure. 
Screen: http://prntscr.com/5dh136

I need to do this for learning automation testing with MonkeyTalk. And in the tutorial I saw, that I need to convert my project (it is neccessary: http://prntscr.com/5dgynd)

Help me please, may be I've installed AspectJ pluggin incorrectly or do something wrong.

Comment: Yes, the menu entry should be there. Which plugin have you installed? What you need is called AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools). Maybe tell us a bit more about Eclipse version, AJDT version, possible error messages when installing or updating AJDT and what else you think might be helpful.

Comment: I use Eclipse Indigo. On the other PC I've installed Eclipse Lune and it's also doesn't work.
For Indigo I've downloaded this ajdt http://prntscr.com/5egn4u.
Did this through "Help->Install New Software--> form archieve and choose the ajdt"
There were no errors. It seem that everything is ok. I've tryied this on two PC with different version of Eclipse and respectively.
If it's necessary, I can make video, how i installed Eclipse and Ajdt plugin.

But I did it as on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJMUgOrffFY

Comment: May be I need to add any path somewhere?

Comment: Also in my eclipse absent this item in Window-Preference-General: http://prntscr.com/5egus7

Comment: I found out how to solve this:) Thanks kriegaex for response. 
Steps to resolving:
Select project, right click -> AspectJ Tools -> Remove AspectJ Capability && Select project, right click -> Configure -> Convert to AspectJ project

Comment: So your project already was an AspectJ project to start with. No surprise that the menu item was not there then. I suggest you delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I successfully did

1) see what is your eclipse version from (Help->About ADT) or (Help->About Eclipse)

2) get the url of AspectJ from this url https://eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/

3) goto Help->Install New Software and add the path

install the software and enjoy! see the video for detail help : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJMUgOrffFY

Hope it helps :)